# Android Manifest parsing during installation

Tags: android, tags, installation, manifest

I want to learn the installation steps in android. 
I was just wondering how the manifest file is being parsed and validated.
Is it possible to prevent the application from getting installed except for the ones i write or sign. 
My initial thoughts say we should have custom tags in the manifest file(dont know how far is it possible)
Any views ??

Answer (score 0):

The format of the Android Manifest is fully described in [the dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

I don’t understand your other question.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, I already read about the manifest file in the dev guide. Sorry for not being clear.
I wanted to ask if i can have an android system which will allow only applications written by me to get installed. Other application should be rejected by the system.

Comment: Everything is possible, but you will most likely have to build a custom Android ROM. Moreover, you will not be able to install any Google application (Android Market, Gmail, …) nor any launcher, SMS application, telephony application, contacts application, web browser, etc. (unless you rewrite all these applications, of course).  Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Yes, I want only my aplication to run in a particular system.Is there any way to do this by creating custom tags in our manifest file.If so can you please specify the way how we could access that custom tag which is in our manifest file.

Comment: I don’t understand why you are talking about the manifest file. The manifest file can only change the way _a particular application_ will be considered, this will not at all change the behaviour of any other application. If you **really** want a phone without any other application (but I doubt you do, because without launcher you will not even be able to run your own application), check out the [source code of Android](http://android.git.kernel.org/) and build your own ROM.